# Getting inline HTML/JavaScript popup to appear in the middle of screen regardless of resolution

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using the following Javascript and CSS to create popups:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Sys.debug = true;
    var popup;
    Sys.require(Sys.components.popup, function () {
        popup = Sys.create.popup("#popup", {
            parentElementID: "target",
        });
    });
    var popup2;
    Sys.require(Sys.components.popup, function () {
        popup2 = Sys.create.popup("#popup2", {
            parentElementID: "target",
        });
    });
</script>

#popup
{
    width: 400px;
    height: 250px;
    overflow: scroll;
    background-color: #EAFDB3;
    border: solid 2px black;
}
#popup2
{
    width: 400px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: #EAFDB3;
    border: solid 2px black;
}
```

The location these popups appear is done with:

```
 <span id="target" style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; margin-top: -50px; margin-left: -100px;"></span>
```

The content of the popup goes between:

```
<div id="popup" style="background: #EAFDB3; color: #000; padding: 15px; margin: 0px">CONTENT </div>
```

How can I get this popup to popup in the middle of the screen regardless of resolution?

Comment: Have you tried `margin: auto auto`?

Comment: there's a handful of stackoverflow questions of a similar nature. have you looked at the solutions to those?

Comment: Yes I have checked other questions, margin:auto auto does not appear to work

Comment: Are you looking for a pure CSS solution?  Otherwise you can get the width of the window or parent, whichever the case may be, divide it by 2 and offset by half the width of the popup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set top to 50%, left to 50%.  Then have a negative left margin that is half of the width of the popup, and a negative top margin that is half of the height of the popup.  What you have seems to be close...

But margin-top should be -125px and margin-left should be -200px, given a popup that is 400x250 in size.

Answer (score 2):

For dynamically-sized popups, consider wrapping your content in div.vc-outer and div.vc-inner.

CSS

```
.vc-outer {
  display: table;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; }

.vc-inner {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle; }

.popup {
  display: inline-block; }
```

HTML

```
<div class="vc-outer"><div class="vc-inner">
  <div class="popup">Hey!</div>
</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are giving inline style(even same property) as well as using ID. I will suggest to do this only once and that to using ID.